# ellipsis in div with width controlled by float

Tags: css

I am trying to emulate a facebook-like layout with a profile picture floated left and a name and tagline to the right.  The problem is that I am trying to make it a semi-fluid layout, and at small screen sizes (or long taglines/names) the text may need to be truncated.

The problem is that I can't get an elipsis overflow without losing my float or my fluid sizing.

```
<div style="-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;float:left;width: 105px;height: 105px; padding: 5px 5px 0 0;border-radius:0 7px 0 0;background-color:#fff; margin:-50px 10px 0 0;z-index:100;position:relative;">
    <img src="" alt="" style="width: 100px;height:100px;margin:0;padding:0;border-radius:0 5px 0 0;">
</div>
<div style="width:100%;text-overflow: ellipsis;">
    <h2 style="text-align:left;margin:0;">John Jacob Smith</h2>
    <p style="text-align:left;margin:0;white-space:nowrap;">
        This is a potentially very long tagline that I want to dynamically truncate with ellipsis.
    </p>
</div>
```

I have a link to my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/GxvLa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `overflow: hidden` on your `<p>`. [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/GxvLa/3/):

```
#desc p {
    margin: 0;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: That's it!  I have no reason why I missed it, but I was assuming I needed to explicitly set the width of the element!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `overflow:hidden` for your tagline.
Still, it is not clear what you want to truncate it to.  The containing div is 100%.